# Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I got mistake when try to open admin page on my project. Trouble in line of urls.py

```
url(r'^letter/([a-zA-Z0-9µ])/$', common.views.letters),
```

error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in         _populate, line 264
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Project except admin page work fine. I understand that problem in "µ". But how to make it work ?

First line of urls.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the encoding to be used explicitly like this

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
print (r'^letter/([a-zA-Z0-9µ])/$')
```

**Output**

```
^letter/([a-zA-Z0-9µ])/$
```

Comment: @aIKid Learning from my mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

As u first line.

Comment: Sorry, that missed this moment in my post. "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" already present.